# How to copy a nested list without causing a StackOverflowError

Tags: java, arrays, clone

I have an ArrayList holding many Team objects. I need to create a deep clone of this arraylist, but each Team object has an ArrayList of more Team objects. When the size of the mother ArrayList reaches the hundreds, I get a StackOverflow error.

I wrote a utility function to deep clone arraylists by calling Team::clone() on each element. Team::clone() is overridden to return a deep copy of the Team object. Team::clone() includes a call to to utility deepclone function to make a clone of its own arraylist

If you need the code

```java
class Team {
    int foo;
    ArrayList<Team> teams;


    public Team(int foo, ArrayList<Team> bar){
        teams=bar;
        foo=foo;
    }

    @Override
    public Team clone(){
        new Team(foo,deepclone(teams));
    }


    public static ArrayList<Team> deepclone(ArrayList<Team> in){
        ArrayList<Team> ret=new ArrayList<>();

        for(Team t:in) {
            ret.add(t.clone());
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
         //already have a huge ArrayList of teams
         deepclone(thebigarraylist);
    }
}
```

Comment: To confirm, how deeply nested is the list? (How many nested levels of lists are there?)

Comment: There is usually only one more level inside the mother array but in special cases, the levels may increase indefinitely

Comment: You can use a stack structure to simulate recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If there are enough levels of nesting, and hence recursion, a `StackOverflowError` is inevitable. One thing you could try is to inline `deepclone` to nearly half the number of levels of recursion, doubling the number of levels of nesting allowed. You can also make `Team` implement `Cloneable` and make `deepclone` generic (renamed to `deepCloneIterable`). (Note: not tested!)

```java
class Team implements Cloneable {
    int foo;
    ArrayList<Team> teams;


    public Team(int foo, ArrayList<Team> bar){
        teams = bar;
        foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public Team clone(){
        ArrayList<Team> teamsCopy = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Team team : teams) {
            teamsCopy.add(team.clone());
        }

        return new Team(foo, teamsCopy);
    }

    public static ArrayList<T> deepCloneIterable(Iterable<T> in){
        ArrayList<T> out = new ArrayList<>();

        for(T t : in) {
            out.add(t.clone());
        }

        return out;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
         //already have a huge ArrayList of teams
         deepCloneIterable(thebigarraylist);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was imagining some way of serializing, but I'll give this solution a try

Comment: You *could* serialize and then unserialize it, but it would probably be pretty inefficient. Another option would be to go through the nested lists manually by keeping track of the current index at each depth in a list or stack, as [@shmosel alluded to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140495/how-to-copy-a-nested-list-without-causing-a-stackoverflowerror/56140680?noredirect=1#comment98911612_56140495). I have to go now, though.